# How can I make a unlink button in PHP

Tags: php

I have a **PHP script** where you can upload files. These files get listed, and are converted to a download link. The last thing that I need is a delete button for each list item. Like so

- test.txt X

(The large X should be a delete button).

This is my code so far.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
  }


   $thelist = "";
   if ($handle = opendir('uploads')) {
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
              $thelist .= '<li><a download="'.$file.'"href="uploads/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
           }
      }
    closedir($handle);
  }
?>

<h1>List:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

Im quite new with PHP, so I that hope someone can explain me how it works in easy language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The last thing what I need is a delete button for each list item

Post the value via a form:

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <button type="submit" name="file_id" value="some_value">&times;</button>
</form>
```

And then in `delete.php`, reference `$_POST['file_id']`.

Another method is to wrap your `while` loop in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <?php while(...): ?>
    <button type="submit" name="file_id" value="some_value">&times;</button>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: HTTP method GET is not advised for actions that have this kind of effect. Instead, it should be used only to retrieve some data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods

Comment: I agree with Alejandro. A very risky and unsafe method.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the **X** link for referencing the file to be deleted i.e.

```
$thelist .= '<li><a download="'.$file.'"href="uploads/'.$file.'">'.$file.'  </a> <a href="delete.php?item='.$file.'"> X </a></li>';
```

Then on your delete page you may add the unlink code to delete your file

```
$file = $_GET['item'];
if (!unlink($file))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $file");
}
```

This is the basic idea of how to go about it. 
But to be safe you may encrypt the url file name on the parameter i.e.

```
base64_encode($file)
```

And on the delete page you decode it

```
base64_decode($_GET["item"])
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I understand it. It didn't really work at the beginning, but i changed the location of the delete.php to the uploads directory. (and ofcourse in the code i change the path of delete.php. I can work further with this code. :)

Comment: @StijnWesterhof Check my answer at the top, i have added the **X** for deleting the file. or you need it to be a button?

Comment: Not only is this vulnerable to CSRF attacks. It's also vulnerable to directory traversal attacks making this code a *really* bad idea.

Comment: @PeeHaa which one do you suggest?

Comment: Add CSRF protected and directory traversal prevention.

Comment: Uhm okay, its only a school project so safety does not really matter, but if you guys have safer suggestions, feel free to show me them :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a request for deleting the item, you can for instance:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token">
  <input type="hidden" name="file" value="$file">     
  <button type="submit">X</button>
</form>
```

Basically `$csrf_token` is a secure random token which is tied to the session, which the server should validate before processing the delete request.
(Updated regarding CSRF security concerns @PeeHaa mentioned.)
(You can use method DELETE if you support it.)

Comment: This allows random people to trick the user into deleting random files because of the CSRF vulnerability you have just introduced.